# ActiveRecord uniqueness validation prevents update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I'm writing a web app using Rails, part of which includes giving users the ability to leave reviews for things. I wanted to put a validation in the `review` model to ensure that one user can't leave multiple reviews of the same item, so I wrote this:

```
class NoDuplicateReviewValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    dup_reviews = Review.where({user_id: record.user,
                                work_id: record.work})
    unless dup_reviews.length < 1
      record.errors[:duplicate] << "No duplicate reviews!"
    end
  end
end
```

This validator has the desired behavior, i.e. it guarantees that a user can't review a work twice. However, it has the undesired side-effect that a user can't update an already existing review that he/she left. I'm using a really simple

```
def update
  @review.update(review_params)
  respond_with(@work)
end
```

in the reviews controller. How can I change either the validator or the update method so that duplicate reviews are prevented but updates are allowed?

I'm very new to Rails and web development, so I'm sure I've done something goofy here. I didn't use one of the built-in `unique` validators because what is unique is the `user`/`work` pair; there can more than one review by the same user of different works, and there can be more than one review of the same work by different users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`validates_uniqueness_of`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of) on multiple attributes, like this:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :work_id
```

Then a user would not be allowed to review a already reviewed work.

Answer (score 1):

@Sharvy Ahmed's answer is definitely the best, as long as the case is simple enough – the OP's case seems like one of them.

However, if the conditions are more complex, you may need/want to write your custom validation. For that purpose, here's an example (checked with Rails 6.0).

```rb
class NoDuplicateReviewValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    dup_reviews = Review.where(user_id: record.user,
                               work_id: record.work)
    dup_reviews = dup_reviews.where.not(id: record.id) unless record.new_record?

    if dup_reviews.count > 0
      record.errors[:duplicate] << "No duplicate reviews!"
    end
  end
end
```

The idea is,

1. In create, all the relevant DB records retrieved with `where` can and should be used to judge the uniqueness. In the example `new_record?` is used to check it out, but it is actually redundant (because nil `id` matches no records).
2. In update, the DB row of the `record` to update must be excluded from the unique comparison. Otherwise, the update would always fail in the validation.
3. The `count` method is slightly more efficient in terms of DB transaction.